# Not able to copy paste javascript to aspx page.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I copy paste the below line from a working html page to aspx page, it is giving me a error - "The name 'name' doesnt exsist in the current context"

```
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
```

The issue is basically with <% and %> used in the javascript. How to escape this when taking it to an aspx page ?

Comment: Why are you placing this JavaScript directly in your ASPX page? You can put JavaScript in a .js file and reference it from your ASPX page. This will avoid the Web Forms engine trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Placed the script in a separate .js file and things worked fine.